# @Query annotation not working in Spring boot with Oracle database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to execute an Insert statement but unfortunately, I am not able to save the data into the data base.
May be the @Query annotation here is not working correctly.

below are my classes.
Controller:

```
@Component
//@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class EmployeeControllerImpl implements EmployeeController{
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    @Override
    @PostMapping("/addEmployee")
    public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
        return employeeService.addEmployee(emp);
        }

}
```

Service:

```
@Component
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{
    
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    @Override
    public Employee addEmployee(Employee emp) {
    
        return employeeRepository.addEmployee(emp);
    }
}
```

Repository Interface:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer > {

    @Query(value = "insert into employee (fname, lname, gender, age, contactNumber, empEmail, empPass) "
            + "VALUES (:fname, :lname, :gender, :age, :contactNumber, :empEmail, :empPass)", nativeQuery = true)
    Employee addEmployee(Employee emp );
}
```

Employee.java:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int empId;
    @Column
    private String fname;
    @Column
    private String lname;
    @Column
    private String gender;
    @Column
    private int age;
    @Column
    private String contactNumber;
    @Column
    private String empEmail;
    @Column
    private String empPass;
}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port:8082

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=oracle
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Project structure:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your source code, cf. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: I have added the source code, can you please check now?

Comment: I suggest you use the `.save()` method - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-crud-repository-save

Answer (score 0):

There is already a save() method in JpaRepository. You can make use of that in your service class.

```
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{
    
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    @Override
    public Employee addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        return employeeRepository.save(emp);
    }
}
```

Also, in your entity class, when you are using lombok, you just need to add @Data. This will include @Getters and @Setters, so you don't need to add the separately. So it would look like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee
```

Also you should use @Controller and @Service instead of @Component. It specifies which layer the code is supposed to be in.